# std::out_of_range is only thrown in release mode, not in debug mode

Tags: c++, debugging, exception, std

In my program I get an `std::out_of_range` exception if I run it in release mode. It runs fine in debug mode. I use a lot of `std::vector`s, hence I guess it comes from a `myvec.at(100)` call.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 100) >= this->size() (which is 100)
```

Since it does not throws in debug mode, I can not catch the exception and thus debugging is difficult. Is there an easy way to handle this?

Also, I assume that my problem is caused by some undefined behaviour and thus it behaves differently in debug and release. Is that correct?

Comment: To locate the call, divide and conquer with some try/catch blocks. And yes, likely there is another bug hiding.

Comment: Your guess is correct but considering that it's very unlikely to be a bug in std::vector, i'd wager your debug code never accesses element 100

Comment: look for an uninitialized variable

Comment: Actually, you can include debug symbols in the release code and run it in the debugger, on many platforms, but this one feels like an uninitialized variable.  Something you think starts at 0, but is really undefined, but which the debug build automatically initializes in zero-filled space, whereas the release code optimizes out that initialization.